# `pre` max-height not correct

Tags: support, feature-request, bug, status-completed

When looking at the code blocks from the editor, I saw that I got a scroll bar even when not necessary (only a small bit of the last line is outside the pre-viewport). The problem behind this is the definition for `line-height` at `.post-text { line-height: 1.4em !important; }` and the `pre { max-height: 600px; }` definition for the code blocks.

1. `line-height` doesn't have a unit. It's x *times/by* the font-size. If you remove the unit, you already got a working solution.
2. If you don't need valid css and stay (wrong) with units for `pre` definitions, then the `max-height` should be set to `44em`.

*Don't know if it's tagged correctly. If you feel that the tags are wrong, please edit. Thanks.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have removed the em unit for the post-text line-height. good catch! the change will be in the next production deployment. I've made the changes on the main site and meta.

Comment: +1 &... Thanks :)